# Jbutton on a Jtable cell works only once

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am quite new with Java Swing and have some problems with Jbutton on a Jtable cell.

The problem is Jbutton works only once and then it is not functioning.
After first time, when I click on again nothing happens, getTableCellEditorComponent is called only once.
I want it to work as a regular button.

My Button editor and button renderer classes are as follows:

```
package buttonontable;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


 public class MyButtonEditor extends JButton implements TableCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;
  ButtonOnJtableAction buttonOnJtableAction;

  String labelStr;




  public MyButtonEditor(String buttonStr,ButtonOnJtableAction _buttonOnJtableAction) {
    super(buttonStr);
    buttonOnJtableAction = _buttonOnJtableAction;
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    System.out.println("MyButtonEditor constructed");

     }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {


        System.out.println("getTableCellEditorComponent");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table, "Pressed at " + row + "x" + column);
        buttonOnJtableAction.buttonPressed(table,row,column);
        return this;
    }

    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        System.out.println("cancelCellEditing");
        System.out.println("Cancel");
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        System.out.println("stopCellEditing");
        return true;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        System.out.println("getCellEditorValue");
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    protected void fireCellEditing(ChangeEvent e){

    }

}



    package buttonontable;

    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


        public class MyButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

          String buttonStr;
          public MyButtonRenderer(String _buttonStr) {
            setOpaque(true);
            buttonStr = _buttonStr;
            setText(buttonStr);
          }

          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

           System.out.println("getTableCellRendererComponent");

            if (isSelected) {
              setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
              setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else{
              setForeground(table.getForeground());
              setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            setText( (value ==null) ? buttonStr : value.toString() );
            return this;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Post all your classes, including ButtonOnJTableAction and your main() (use a pastebin if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I have to do this I refer to http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ then go to JTable on the left of the page and at the beginning of the JTable javadoc page there is a link to "How to use Tables".  Near the bottom is an example of how to put a button in a JTable.  Looks like the section in that page is "Using Other Editors".  I usually follow what SUN specified.  Hopefully that helps a bit...

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to work as a regular button.

If that means you want to invoke an Action when the button is pressed then you can check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Esc` and click again. If it works now, it's a focus issue.
Don't fix that, follow [camickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461184/jbutton-on-a-jtable-cell-works-only-once/4463514#4463514) or a [spin-off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3606864/192958) of it.

A basic outline should like this:

Renderer:

```
class MyClassCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

private final JButton button;

public MyClassCellRenderer() {
  button = new JButton();
  button.setFocusable(false);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
  button.setText(((Contact)value).getName());
  return button;
}
}
```

Editor:

```
class MyClassCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
private final JButton button;

public MyClassCellEditor() {
  button = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      logger.trace("I");
    }
  });
  button.setFocusable(false);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
  button.setText(((Contact)value).getName());
  return button;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
  return null;
}
}
```

Usage:

```
model.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new MyClassCellRenderer());
model.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new MyClassCellEditor());
```

Comment: I tried 2use the same pattern as u did.
But, if i use jpanel as a container within the jtable's cell, and then I put another button inside of that jpanel, the button itself doesn't animate properly. :(

Comment: "doesn't animate properly" - animate press/release? animate mouse over?